# Using .trigger to click a div simulate clicking an anchor link does not work

Tags: jquery

I have assigned a `div's` 2nd `Id` to be a class of an `<a>` tag. when you click this `div`, it will simulate clicking the `<a>` tag.

```js
$(".component-data").click(function(){
  var partNo = $(this).attr('id').split(' ')[1];
  var tableEQV = ("'a."+partNo+"'");
  $(tableEQV).trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="58 59" class="component-data">comp data(click me for google)</div>
<div id="60 61" class="component-data">comp data(click me for facebook)</div>
<br />
<a class="59" href="http://www.google.com">link to simulate going to google</a>
<br />
<a class="61" href="http://www.facebook.com">link to simulate going to facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/253/)**.

If you clean the `tableEQV` variable and use `[0]` in the click call it should work :

```
$(".component-data").click(function(){
  var partNo = $(this).attr('id').split(' ')[1];
  var tableEQV = "a."+partNo;

  $(tableEQV)[0].click();
});
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".component-data").click(function(){
  var partNo = $(this).attr('id').split(' ')[1];
  var tableEQV = "a."+partNo;

  $(tableEQV)[0].click();
});

//Just for demonstration
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  console.log('Anchor clicked');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="58 59" class="component-data">comp data(click me for google)</div>
<div id="60 61" class="component-data">comp data(click me for facebook)</div>
<br />
<a class="59" href="http://www.google.com">link to simulate going to google</a>
<br />
<a class="61" href="http://www.facebook.com">link to simulate going to facebook</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.trigger("click");` **works only on the click event that are attached using jquery**. And it will not simulate a click on the anchor tag as if it was a real mouse click.

> Triggering a click via JavaScript will not open a hyperlink. This is a security measure built into the browser.

**Solution:** is to use `.click()`

```
$(tableEQV)[0].click();
```

Note that this calls the DOM native click method instead of the jQuery click method, which is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Your reference to `a` tag is incorrect.

Problemactic code :

```
 var tableEQV = ("'a."+partNo+"'");
```

It should be rather,

```
var tableEQV = "a."+partNo;
```

```js
$(".component-data").click(function() {
  var partNo = $(this).attr('id').split(' ')[1];
  //form correct a tag with class selector
  var tableEQV = "a." + partNo;
  //trigger click on anchor tag 
  $(tableEQV).trigger("click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="58 59" class="component-data">comp data(click me for google)</div>
<div id="60 61" class="component-data">comp data(click me for facebook)</div>
<br />
<a class="59" href="http://www.google.com">link to simulate going to google</a>
<br />
<a class="61" href="http://www.facebook.com">link to simulate going to facebook</a>
```